# How to create a instance in Java when we have object of type Class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am currently working on using annotations in my Spring Boot Application. Where I am getting a successful annotation class in the below way:

```
Class s = applicationContext.getType(beanName);
```

After which I also able to get annotated method (with some if checks)

```
Method[] methods = s.getMethods();
```

I would like to invoke a particular method

```
Object result = method.invoke(?, args);
```

However the signature of invoke requires instance of the Class passed to it. I am not sure how I can get instance or object of that class?

[image]

Comment: Use `s.getConstructor()` and then invoke that `Constructor`

Comment: @user thanks. it solved the problem. Please put in a proper answer, such that I can mark it complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want a `Class` instance there: you either want the actual instance on which the method is to be invoked (if it's an instance method), or `null` (if it's a static method).

It's not entirely clear what you intend to do, but if `method` is an instance method, you need an instance of `s` on which to invoke it. If `s` has a no-arg constructor, then you can do

```
Object result = method.invoke(s.getConstructor().newInstance(), args);
```

For constructors with other signatures, provide the type of the parameters to `getConstructor()` and the values for the parameters to `newInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. But it wasnt a static method.

Comment: @Smit Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Unable to accept it for next 7 mins, will do so soon after that.